# How can i use prefetch_related on related_name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a Product model.This model have a categories ManyToMany field. Also i have a ProductPhoto model and this model have a product FK field.And this field have a related_name product_photos.

My query like this.

```py
    Product.objects.prefetch_related('categories', 'product_photos')
    Product.objects.prefetch_related(
                'categories',
                Prefetch(
                    'product_photos', ProductPhoto.objects.select_related('product')
                )
```

Categories is run perfect with innerjoin. But product_photos does not work. Every each row call the sql again because of get the photos.Like

```sql
SELECT ••• FROM "core_productphoto" WHERE ("core_productphoto"."product_id" = 1729)
```

```py
# Product Model
class Product(models.Model):
    categories = TreeManyToManyField(
        to='ProductCategory', related_name='products', verbose_name=_('categories')
    )

class ProductPhoto(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        to='Product',
        related_name='product_photos',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    photo = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=255,
    )
```

Comment: Can you add the model configuration?

Comment: Sure, added model

Comment: Why select related on `product` inside the prefetch? product is already loaded in the main query. This first version `Product.objects.prefetch_related('categories', 'product_photos')` should work

Comment: But doesn't work.  If i use `Product.objects.prefetch_related('categories', 'product_photos')` , every each product calls the sql for get the photos.